# using of sessions in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, session

how to use session in userid...
i.e i have a user table in which there is column userid and also  leave table and in this table there is also a userid to show that which userid apply for leave 
when employee apply for leave then his/her userid also save in leave table...in user table there is all info of employee

```
  protected void Btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try

        {

            int users = aa.SignIn(txt_username.Value, txt_pass.Value);



           if (users == 1)

            {
                //Session["UserID"] = aa.SignIn(txt_username.Value, txt_pass.Value);

                Session["UserID"] = txt_username.Value;

                Session["UserTypeID"] = users;

                Response.Redirect("AdminOp.aspx");

            }

            else if (users == 2)

            {
                //Session["UserID"] = aa.SignIn(txt_username.Value, txt_pass.Value);


                Session["UserID"] = txt_username.Value;

                Session["UserTypeID"] = users;

                Response.Redirect("leave.aspx");

            }


        }

        catch

        {

            Label8.Text= "Incorrect User Name or Password";

        }
```

in this code i save a username in session

Comment: what is problem with this code? what do u exactly want?

Comment: this is code of login for all users type and i want a save userid in session

Comment: Sessions are not the best way to setup a proper authentication system. You should check [ASP.NET Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/eeyk640h(v=vs.100).aspx) for other solutions that will be much more reliable.

Comment: Put Session["UserID"] = txt_username.Value; and Session["UserTypeID"] = users; outside if condition.

Answer (score -1):

You need to fetch the `userid` while validating the user and after validating the user you need to assign the value of `userid` to `Session["UserID"]` and on the basis of `session["UserID"]` you have to work further.

Comment: Please improve this answer or remove it. Some punctuation would possibly help in understanding what you mean.

Comment: When you are verifying the user with SignIn function to validate the user. if user is validated then you are getting the value of User as integer along with the users you need to get the value of UserID from database and assign into session for further work.

Comment: When you are verifying the user through SignIn function for user exists or not. within the same query you can get the value of userid from table and after validating the user you can assign the value of userid in session.